# Cannot access resource by using the getResources() method

Tags: java, getresource

I have the following project-tree:

[image]

I can access the 290.gif file in the path: **Java GUI/src/dk/resources/290.gif** by using the following command:

```
this.getClass().getResource("/dk/resources/290.gif")
```

But I *can't* access the 290.gif file in the path: **Java GUI/resources2/290.gif** by using the following command:

```
this.getClass().getResource("/resources2/290.gif")
```

I am trying to access the 290.gif file from the HelloWorldFrame.java class.
I want to access the 290.gif file in the path: **Java GUI/resources2/290.gif**!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared both `src` and `resources2` directories as *source folders* in Eclipse.
When Eclipse builds your app, it copies recources to the `build` folder, and so:

- the files from `dk.resources` **package** are accessible via `/dk/resources/290.gif`
- the files from `resources2` **folder** are not in any package, and are accessible via `/290.gif`

If you want the file to be accessible via `/resources2/290.gif`, then create a package named `resource2` under the `src` folder.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that the folders `src` and `resources2` are both in the build path. Have you tried `this.getClass().getResource("/290.gif")`?

Answer (score 0):

During runtime of the artifact you can access resources with

```
InputStream resource = SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("<file or directory name"))
```

or

```
URL resource = SomeClass.class.getResource("<file or directory name"))
```

where SomeClass is a class in the artifact. The first way will give you an InputStream that you can use to read the contents of the file, the second way will return a URL that you can use to find out the path of the file or directory or move along the directory tree.